# How do you stop the image overlapping the UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I use `SDWebImage` do add the image to my `UIImageView`

```
if let url = URL(string: user.imageLocation) {
        cell.userImageView.borderColor = UIColor.white
        cell.userImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "account"), options: .init(), completed: nil)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    } else {
        cell.userImageView.borderColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.userImageView.image = UIImage.accountImage
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Even though the `UIImageView` is set to `.scaleAspectFit` and `clipToBounds` is set to `true` The image is still bigger than the `UIImageView`

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height / 2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    imageView.borderColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
```

[image: Image showing the image overlapping the UIImageView]

Comment: You should set the clipsToBounds for the imageView's superview.

Comment: Tried that it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved it was after the new `image` is added the `UIImageView` `clipsToBounds` is changed back to false. So after adding the image you should set `clipsToBounds` to true again.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You’d better add your imageView to a container view and this container will have the white border you need. Then you set the clipsToBounds of the container to true.

Comment: @Asteroid Why is that a better solution?

Comment: First of all you will have one extra operation to carry out each time you set an image. Secondly, it might cause visual glitches and the user might actually see that the image is turning circular from rectangular (might not be noticeable though)